# Redirect output in a bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, redirect

I have a bash script that runs something along the lines of:

```
python myscript.py --input=/path/file --someOption=value > /path/file
```

If I ran it without the redirect, everything works fine. If I run it with the redirect, the file gets truncated. I suspect python is executing the whole line including the redirect when in fact the redirect has to be executed by bash.

I tried:

`exec "python myscript.py --input=/path/file --someOption=value"` but I get command not found error.

How do I get python to execute just the python portion, and the redirect to be executed by bash?

Comment: python isn't doing the redirect, the shell is, and yes it does that before running the command. I don't know what you were expecting that `exec` attempt to do exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't read from and write to the same file at the same time.

Redirect output to a temporary location and then overwrite the input:

```
if python myscript.py --input=/path/file --someOption=value > /path/file.tmp
then
  mv /path/file.tmp /path/file
fi
```

Comment: I thought the python will read the file in, process it, print the results to stdout, then terminate at which point the output will be redirected.

Comment: @ventsyv, redirection happen *before* the command is started; in this case, it runs the command with its FD 1 writing to the already-truncated `/path/file` inode. Since it's already truncated, one obviously can't read input from there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using same file as input and output. Shell first opens the redirected file and it becomes empty. Your python script reads the empty file then.

It can easily be solved by using **`tee`**.

```
python myscript.py --input=/path/file --someOption=value | tee /path/otherfile
```

Comment: `tee` isn't necessary here; you're just using a different output file, which will work with simple redirection as well.

Comment: That was my old answer. As someone already covered it, I mentioned `tee`